# How to create custom build.prop file to custom directory in aosp?

Tags: android, android-source, system-properties

I am working on aosp and have two questions about build.prop.

1) Normally, build.prop file is located to /system directory. I'd like create to custom build.prop file and save it to different directory. For example, I have tvconfig directory and want to create it in here. Could I read properties from /tvconfing/build.prop via SystemProperties?

2) Could I use different name for prop file except build.prop for example mycustom.prop

Answer (score 0):

There's a partition called oem and you can put your-name.prop file on it and the properties in it is still readable by using getprop.

https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/product-partitions

By the way, why do you need another prop file? What's wrong with just put your property in build.prop?